# Using ajax in form api to insert a view on select list change requires 2 change events to start inserting/replacing content

Tags: 7, views, forms

I'm embedding a [fullcalendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fullcalendar) view into a node edit form.  When the user first lands on the form, he/she does not see a calendar and is prompted to select a room first.

Issue: On the first room selection, all of the JS is loaded but no calendar appears.  On subsequent selections it works as desired.
[image]

Based on the attached screenshot the first call loads everything that fullcalendar needs for the view, so the question is: how do I pre-load that stuff on the page?  I don't want to load up the view display if it's possible to accomplish this without doing so.  (In the interim, I'm using a hidden form element; doing this allows for it to work fine and there are other ways to add it to the page so that the user doesn't see it, but I'd prefer to avoid it).

```
// in hook_form_alter()
...
$form['field_time_and_place'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['field_room_reference'][LANGUAGE_NONE] += [
  '#ajax' => [
    'callback' => 'cela_events_ajax_update_calendar_view',
    'wrapper' => 'js--cela-events-room-schedule',
    'method' => 'replace',
  ],
];

$form['field_time_and_place'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['field_room_calendar'] = [
  '#title' => t('Room Calendar'),
  '#markup' => 'Please select a room to view the calendar',
  '#prefix' => '<div id="js--cela-events-room-schedule">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
];
...
// end hook_form_alter()

function cela_events_ajax_update_calendar_view($form, $form_state) {
  $room = $form_state['values']['field_time_and_place'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['field_room_reference'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['nid'];
  $view = views_embed_view('cela_calendars', 'block_2', $room);
  $form['field_time_and_place']['field_room_calendar']['#markup'] = $view;

  return $form['field_time_and_place']['field_room_calendar'];
}
```

In case it helps, here is a screenshot of kpr() after the #ajax has been added to the form element.  This is `kpr($form['field_time_and_place'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['field_room_reference'][LANGUAGE_NONE]);`

[image: screenshot of array]

Comment: You probably need to put the event on `$form['field_time_and_place']['field_room_reference'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['nid']` or `$form['field_time_and_place']['field_room_reference'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['nid']`, so it targets the form element rather than the Drupal field

Comment: @Clive, I may have created some confusion when trying to clean up the code so I just edited it with an as-is copy/paste (was trying to get rid of the deep array).  Your suggestions get the unsupported operand error unless I'm doing it wrong.